# Ruby - Initialize has key-value in a loop

Tags: ruby

I have a hash of key value pairs, similar to -

```
myhash={'test1' => 'test1', 'test2 => 'test2', ...}
```

how can I initialize such a hash in a loop? Basically I need it to go from 1..50 with the same test$i values but I cannot figure out how to initialize it properly in a loop instead of doing it manually.
I know how to loop through each key-value pair individually:

```
 myhash.each_pair do |key, value|
```

but that doesn't help with init

Comment: Your hash is invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
hash = (1..50).each.with_object({}) do |i, h|
    h["test#{i}"] = "test#{i}"
end
```

---

If you want to do this lazily, you could do something like below:

```
hash = Hash.new { |hash, key| key =~ /^test\d+/ ? hash[key] = key : nil}
p hash["test10"]
#=> "test10"
p hash
#=> {"test10"=>"test10"}
```

The block passed to `Hash` constructor will be invoked whenever a key is not found in hash, we check whether key follows a certain pattern (based on your need), and create a key-value pair in hash where value is equal to key passed.

Answer (score 4):

```
(1..50).map { |i| ["test#{i}"] * 2 }.to_h
```

The solution above is more DRY than two other answers, since `"test"` is not repeated twice :)

It is BTW, approx 10% faster (that would not be a case when keys and values differ):

```
require 'benchmark'
n = 500000
Benchmark.bm do |x| 
  x.report { n.times do   ; (1..50).map { |i| ["test#{i}"] * 2 }.to_h ; end }
  x.report { n.times do   ; (1..50).each.with_object({}) do |i, h| ; h["test#{i}"] = "test#{i}" ; end ; end }
end

     user     system      total        real
17.630000   0.000000  17.630000 ( 17.631221)
19.380000   0.000000  19.380000 ( 19.372783)
```

Or one might use `eval`:

```
hash = {}
(1..50).map { |i| eval "hash['test#{i}'] = 'test#{i}'" }
```

or even `JSON#parse`:

```
require 'json'
JSON.parse("{" << (1..50).map { |i| %Q|"test#{i}": "test#{i}"| }.join(',') << "}")
```

Comment: `* 2` is awesome, even it's a bit obscure

Comment: Will work only if it is assumed that both key and value start with same string (i.e. `test`).

Comment: @WandMaker Indeed. But changing `["test#{i}"] * 2` to `["test#{i}", "quest#{i}"]` is not a rocket science.

Comment: @mudasobwa Agreed, but will your benchmark hold good in that case?  I am seeing opposite results.

Comment: I ran benchmarks exactly for what was stated in OP.

Comment: @mudasobwa Your answer critiqued other answers on two points - they are not DRY and slower - all I am saying is that `DRY` part makes your answer bit restrictive and benchmarks don't hold if you remove the restriction forced by DRY.

Comment: @WandMaker I added a comment _“that would not be a case when keys and values differ”_.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there's [Array#to_h](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h), which converts an array of key-value pairs into a hash.

Second, you can just initialize such a hash in a loop, just do something like this:

```
target = {}
1.upto(50) do |i|
  target["test_#{i}"] = "test_#{i}"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

```
hash = Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = k.itself}
(1..50).each{|i| hash["test#{i}"]}
hash # => ...
```

Comment: This apparently produces the hash, that behaves slightly different. I believe OP does not expect the hash to return a value on any key.

Comment: @mudasobwa The difference would not cause difference in behaviour unless the OP calls the hash with an undefined key. But if that is still a problem, then the default proc can be removed after creating the hash.